# cannot checkout a branch although it exists

Tags: git, bitbucket, branch, git-checkout

I have 3 branches that I see in bit-bucket, one master and 2 branches other developers have worked on.

I would like to take the latest branch, make a few changes, and merge it into the master. This branch is called "Updated_model_,_sources"
when I review my remote branches (`git branch -r`) I get:

```
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
origin/master
```

So I don't see it there, but when I try `git ls-remote origin` I get:

```
longcodeblablabla HEAD
longcodeblablabla refs/heads/Updated_model_,_sources
..
```

so I see it's there, now the thing is - I just cannot checkout this branch! I tried a lot of different ways to do so but I keep getting:

> error: pathspec 'refs/heads/Updated_model_,_sources' did not match any file(s) known to git

(tried it without the path folders as well).

PS - I did not perform a standard clone, the project piled up to be really heavy so it got stuck in the clone, so I used `git clone --depth 9 blabla@blabla.com`.

Comment: Is the "Updated_model_,_sources" branch pointing to one of the last 9 commits?

Comment: when I run git log I see only 9 commits made to the master branch.. does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

By default, when doing a shallow clone you only get the single branch that the remote's HEAD points to (i.e. `master`). You need to fetch the remote branch you want in order to check it out:

`git fetch origin Updated_model_,_sources:Updated_model_,_sources`

Note that this will grab all ancestors of the branch, which, given that youth used the --depth option with `git clone`, may not be what you want. So, you can pass the --depth option to `git fetch` as well. However, I would highly suggest that you just do a full clone; otherwise, you will be left with a few disconnected branches. Shallow clones are just funky, as you get problems like the one you are seeing now.

Comment: OK I fetched, but I tried "git checkout Updated_model_,_sources" and got the same error.. :/ what can be the problem?

Comment: @Roman, I have updated the answer; note that I altered the `git fetch` a bit. But as I say in the answer, my recommendation would be to just do a full clone.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it but unfortunately I cannot - whenever I try to clone I get this message:
error: RPC failed; result=52, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
I suspect that the project is too big - BTW depth 9 works but depth 10 does not..
I tried increasing the buffer size, but it didn't help also.. :/